# How to add Different flavors to android library in maven?

Tags: maven, gradle, android-library, android-flavors

I have created a library, which is distributed with maven. Right now I would like to add new library as a dependency, which size is more than 8 mb.

I want to make that dependency as optional and this is why I think that creating a **different library flavor** would be correct way (might be wrong, I would be open to other solutions)
However, I searched and found that I can't do that with libraries..

Maybe something changed, or is there a different way to implement optional **dependency to library**, which should be managed by the user who integrates my library. I would like to keep same dependency name in order to maintain only **single version of library**.

Thanks in advance :)